# separate random numbers in tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, grid-layout

This code showed me some random numbers on the right side on my screen.

```
from Tkinter import *
import math
from random import randrange

number=Tk()
number.geometry("1308x720")
number.config(bg="black")
ECG=randrange(0,1000);SP=randrange(0,1000);PLES=randrange(0,1000);show=randrange(0,1000)
c1=StringVar();c2=StringVar();c3=StringVar();c4=StringVar()
c1.set(ECG);c2.set(SP);c3.set(PLES);c4.set(show)
valor_c1=Label(number,textvariable=c1,width=int(c1.get())//10,height=1,fg="red",anchor="ne",bg="black").grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=E)
valor_c2=Label(number,textvariable=c2,width=int(c2.get())//10,height=1,fg="red",anchor="ne",bg="black").grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=E)
valor_c3=Label(number,textvariable=c3,width=int(c3.get())//10,height=1,fg="red",anchor="ne",bg="black").grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=E)
valor_c4=Label(number,textvariable=c4,width=int(c4.get())//10,height=1,fg="red",anchor="ne",bg="black").grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=E)
number.grid_columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
number.mainloop()
```

Now I need to separate the second number 4,5 cm away from the edge, the third number 9 cm away from the edge and the fourth number 13,5 cm away from the edge.
I tried to separate one number of the other changing the number of row, but did not work
To summarizing, my question is: **¿How to separate one number of the other?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pady` or `ipady` option. See [`Tkinter.Grid.grid`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid-method).

```
Label(number,textvariable=c1,width=int(c1.get())//10,height=1,fg="red",anchor="ne",bg="green").grid(row=0,column=2, sticky=E, pady=10)
Label(number,textvariable=c2,width=int(c2.get())//10,height=1,fg="blue",anchor="ne",bg="snow").grid(row=4,column=2, sticky=E, pady=10)
Label(number,textvariable=c3,width=int(c3.get())//10,height=1,fg="cyan",anchor="ne",bg="grey").grid(row=8,column=2, sticky=E, pady=10)
Label(number,textvariable=c4,width=int(c4.get())//10,height=1,fg="gold",anchor="ne",bg="blue").grid(row=16,column=2, sticky=E, pady=10)
#                                                                                                                              ^^^^^^^
```

BTW, you can specify the padding as *pixel*, not as *cm*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you I was trying with pady and ipady but my mistake was that i did not pass of 5. I solved my problem putting a pady over 80 in the second and fourth label. Thank you so much.

Comment: I am going to post a new question about how to combine a pygame program with this code.